# Sent emails with Action Mailer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gmail, actionmailer

I am trying to send an email to example@gmail.com with Action Mailer (Ruby on Rails). The method sendactivation is correctly executed and the message "Email sent" is displayed. However, I never receive any email. Actually, the output "Test" is never printed. My webapp is hosted on Heroku Cedar-10.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def sendactivation
      UserMailer.welcome_email()
      render :json => {
        :result => "Email sent"
      }
    end
  end
end

class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email()
    mail(to: "example@gmail.com",
         body: "Hello",
         content_type: "text/html",
         subject: "Already rendered!")
    puts "Test"
  end
end
```

This is the configuration I have on my config/environment/production.rb. Actually I wanted to send it with Office 365 but I suppose it is easier to debug with a Gmail account.

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    user_name:            'example@gmail.com',
    password:             '########',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I need to change on my Gmail configuration?

**ANSWER:** In addition to the marked answer, I needed to set the "from" address in the welcome_email method.

Comment: You can temporarily set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` and check for errors in your logs.  Separately, I came across [this article](http://blog.mailgun.com/tips-tricks-avoiding-gmail-spam-filtering-when-using-ruby-on-rails-action-mailer/) about setting message ID for Gmail that might be worth reading.  As a last resort, you can [configure Gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) to allow access to less secure application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call method deliver:

```
UserMailer.welcome_email.deliver
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UserMailer.welcome_email.deliver_now
```

From the [Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer): See section 2.1.4

```
class SendWeeklySummary
  def run
    User.find_each do |user|
      UserMailer.weekly_summary(user).deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```